# Doing operations between subsequent elements without using a FOR loop?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, Is it possible to do simple operations between subsequent elements of an array without using a `for` loop? Something like `diff()`. For example, I have this vector:

```
A = [2 4 8 16 32]
```

and I want each element to be divided by its predecessor:

```
ans = [2 2 2 2]
```

How can I do it without going through all elements (without using loops)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that division in Matlab work on both scalars and matrices, if you use the `./` operator rather than `/`

```
>> A = [2 4 8 16 32];
>> A(2:end) ./ A(1:end-1)
ans =
     2     2     2     2
```

Regarding your question about doing `dot()` between vectors stored in the rows of a matrix. There is an additional argument to `dot()` that tells it whether your vectors are stored in columns (the default) or rows;

```
>> x = rand(3);
>> y = rand(3);  # random vectors
>> dot(x,y)      # dot product of column vectors
ans =
    0.5504    0.5561    0.5615
>> dot(x,y,2)    # dot product of row vectors
ans =
    0.3170
    1.0938
    0.2572
```

Most functions in Matlab are vectorized so that they can work on scalars, vectors and matrices, but you sometimes have the read the documentation (e.g. type `help dot`) to work out how to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I knew about the vectorized operations, but the indexing part was a little tricky.